# printf is producing the segmentation fault?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, printf

I'm learning threads and my code runs upto last print statement. Why it is giving segmentation fault at print? I think possible reason could be non-existant address passed as argument to print, but it is not the reason, I'm passing valid address.

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 


void *thread (void *vargp) {
   int arg = *((int*)vargp);
   return &arg;
}   

int main () {
   pthread_t tid;
   int thread_arg = 0x7ffdbc32fa34;
   int *ret_value;
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread, &thread_arg);
   pthread_join(tid, (void **)(&ret_value));
   printf("hello\n");
   printf("%X\n", *ret_value);
   return 0; 
}
```

It is giving following output:

```
hello
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is it because I'm returning an address of a local variable, which gets destroyed once thread is returned? I don't think so, because changing to following code is also giving me segmentation fault!

```
void *thread (void *vargp) {
    int * arg = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *arg = *((int*)vargp);
    return &arg;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it because I'm returning an address of a local variable, which gets
>   destroyed once thread is returned?

Yes, it is.

> I don't think so, because changing to following code is also giving me
>   segmentation fault!

This code is *also* returning the address of a local variable (`return &arg;`).  Instead, you should be returning the pointer value that `malloc()` returned (`return arg;`):

```
void *thread (void *vargp)
{
    int * arg = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *arg = *((int*)vargp);
    return arg;
}
```

You also should not be casting the address of `ret_value` to type `void **` in `main()` - the variable is of type `int *` not `void *`, so it shouldn't be written to through a `void **` pointer (although, in practice, this will usually work).  Instead, you should be using `void *` variable to hold the return value, then either casting this value to `int *` or assigning it to a variable of type `int *`:

```
void *ret_value;
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread, &thread_arg);
pthread_join(tid, &ret_value);
printf("%X\n", *(int *)ret_value);
```